# How to tell useEffect to wait for data API?

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, use-effect

I want to get data from an API and map the response to display it.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

export default function Nav() {

   const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'url',
      headers: {
         'x-rapidapi-host': 'host',
         'x-rapidapi-key': 'key'
      }
   }

   const [allCoins, setAllCoins] = useState([])

   useEffect(() => {
      axios.request(options)
      .then(res => setAllCoins(res.data.data.coins))
      .catch(err => console.error(err))
   }, [])

   return (
      <nav>
          {allCoins.map(el => {
              <img src={el.iconUrl} alt="" />
              <h2>{el.name}</h2>
              <span>{el.symbol}</span>
          })}
      </nav>
   )
}
```

But nothing is displayed. I know it's an asynchronous problem, I have to wait the data in the state before mapping it, but I have no idea how to do it and I didn't find a solution on Google.

Comment: What you've shown seems reasonable. Do you get any errors in the console? What's the actual response from the API?

Comment: I don't get errors in the console, i get the data but only after the return has been executed so there is nothing displayed.

Comment: And then when you setAllCoins the component should re-render with the new data.

Answer (score 0):

Okay finally I solved my problem, it wasn't asynchronous but just syntax mistake.
I used {} instead () for the map arrow function.

```
allCoins.map(el => { ...})❌

allCoins.map(el => ( ...))✅
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to call the api `asynchronously`, which you're not doing in here. If everything else is correct, this two code block should work.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
        const data = await axios.request(options)
        setAllCoins(res?.data?.data?.coins)
    }
    getData()
}, [])
```

We directly implement the async in `useEffect`, we can only achieve this by creating a asynchronous method and call it inside `useEffect hook`.

And also you need to modify your code in map:

```js
{
    allCoins.length > 0 && allCoins.map(el => {
        return <>
            <img src={el.iconUrl} alt="" />
            <h2>{el.name}</h2>
            <span>{el.symbol}</span>
        </>
    })
}
```

> JSX expressions must have one parent element

So you need to wrap your element by one single element or `React.Fragment`.

Comment: There's no point defining an `async` function because you don't `await` anything in it. You just have the same promise chain (which *does* call the API asynchronously) wrapped in a redundant function.

Comment: sorry I forgot to correct his statement.

Comment: They are already calling it asynchronously, whether to use async/await or .then is entirely a matter of choice. The first half of the answer doesn't help solve the problem at all.